I'm trying to automate the google dinosaur game but cannot seem to detect the obstacles
As part of a course I'm on, one of the tasks is to make a program that automatically plays the google dino game. I have tried to check if the pixels are white or not in certain areas of each screenshot that is taken regularly, if they are not white I know there is an obstacle so I want the player to jump by pressing space.
However, the dinosaur only sometimes detects an object and jumps.
How can I get the program to detect the obstacles more consistently?
I've tried checking more pixels and have changed the values many times.
import pyautogui
import time

while True:
    im = pyautogui.screenshot()
#get colour of screen background
    screen = im.getpixel((300, 300))

    x1 = im.getpixel((1400, 627))
    x2 = im.getpixel((1420, 627))
    x3 = im.getpixel((1440, 627))
    x4 = im.getpixel((1460, 627))

    if screen[0] == 247:
        if x1[0] != 247 or x2[0] != 247 or x3[0] != 247 or x4[0] != 247:
            pyautogui.press("space")
            time.sleep(0.0001)


game may run too fast and your code may not catch pixels. Maybe You should check many pixels in some area. And pyautogui has also function to detect object using its image - so it can be useful to detect if it is cactus or bird.

maybe first you could use print() to see what you have in variables. Maybe sometimes it needs to compare it with different values. OR maybe you should get screen[0] only once - before loop - because inside loop it may get different color in some moments.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.
